# How to match begin or end of a line using C#'s Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match this expression:

```
^COMA1TA2000,.*$
```

with this text:

```
# Qualquer linha iniciada por # será ignorada
# Caracteres que não podem serem usados na nomenclatura das copiadoras ou modelos.
# & < > " '
COMA1TA2000,ta-2000,hd,COMB1
#COMA2TA2000,ta-2000,hd,COMB2
#COMA3TA2000,ta-2000,hd,COMB3
```

I can do that using [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), but I can't with the C# [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
content = sr.ReadToEnd();
string pattern =  "^COMA1TA2000,.*$";
if(Regex.IsMatch(content, pattern))
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to be clear, your `IsMatch` line is returning false?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `RegexOptions.Multiline`, like so:

```
Regex.IsMatch(content, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx

If `RegexOptions.Multiline` is not set, `^` and `$` will match beginning and the end* of the *string*, not the *line* like intended.

Comment: Do not forget that Windows uses CRLF line endings, so you may need to use `\r?$` instead of `$` in patterns used with a `RegexOptions.Multiline` option. Here, it does not matter because `.*$` matches all text up to the first newline, LF char. In case you want to check if the line ends with `a`, you will need to write `a\r?$`.

Answer (score 16):

Or set multiline option in regex `(?m)`: `(?m)^COMA1TA2000,.*$`

Comment: In an environment where I only have access to .net regular expressions, not to the code that creates and runs them - I thought I was out of luck, as it seemed like setting the multiline option was necessary for what I was trying to do. That totally works! Learned something new and nifty. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `File.ReadLines` instead of `ReadToEnd` method and apply regex on each line.

What you're doing now, is reading the entire text as a block of text and MultiLine option sometimes breaks things down (as there are different CRLF characters in different operating systems, and stuff like that).

My suggestion is this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path to your text file");
Regex regex = new Regex("^pattern$");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(line.Trim())
    if (match.Successful)
    {
         // have your match here.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice idea I will remember that in my next project. But for this question the first answer is the correct.