# Replace a string in multiline regex with end of line token

Tags: c#, regex

I got the following regex

```
var fixedString = Regex.Replace(subject, @"(:[\w]+ [\d]+)$", "", 
                                                        RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

which doesn't work. It works if I use `\r\n`, but I would like to support all types of line breaks. As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6596091/70386) states I have to use `RegexOptions.Multiline` to be able to use `$` as end of line token (instead of end of string). But it doesn't seem to help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, I think I understood, you want to replace also the newline character at the end of the row.

The problem is the `$` is a zero width assertion. It does not match the newline character, it matches the position **before** `\n`.

You could do different other things:

1. If it is OK to match all following newlines, means also all following empty rows, you could do this:

   ```
   var fixedString = Regex.Replace(subject, @"(:[\w]+ [\d]+)[\r\n]+", "");
   ```
2. If you only want to match the newline after the row and keep following empty rows, you have to make a pattern for all possible combinations, e.g.:

   ```
   var fixedString = Regex.Replace(subject, @"(:[\w]+ [\d]+)\r?\n", "");
   ```

   This would match the combination `\n` and `\r\n`

Comment: ahh ok. I just thought that `$` just like using any kind of new line combination. But it matches end of line as in after any NL chars, right?

Comment: It matches the end of line before the newline characters, but it does just match that position, it does not match any character.