# Cannot extract url from text (Regex C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract an url from a string with a regex for an automated test. The thing is, in https://regexr.com/7an5r the pattern seems to be right and it does the job, but when I use it in the code, the regex doesn't match anything and it returns an empty string. The url within the text:

- starts always with "https://" and
- ends with an \r (that I'll remove later)

```
    string html = text;
    string pattern = @"https:\/\/(.+?)\\r";
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match urlMatch = r.Match(html);
    string url = urlMatch.Value;
```

What's wrong with the pattern to be used in .NET?

Comment: Why use regex, why not just split by newline? The message seems to be an automated and predictable format.

Comment: Seems to be working here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nGQgJY

Comment: If `\r` means end of line, then try to use `$` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match begin or end of a line using C#'s Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596060/how-to-match-begin-or-end-of-a-line-using-cs-regex)

Comment: Try using `(?m)https:\/\/\S+$` https://regex101.com/r/f4bkBF/1